# Foxit Reader chaged default file association

Tags: applications, system

After I installed Foxit Reader, when I click any file starts with`.`, e.g. `.bashrc`, The Foxit Reader will open it, and if I change the  application to a text editor and set it as the default, it only change the file I selected, (e.g. ,I changed the default app  with `.bashrc` to gedit,and it can be opened by gedit by default,but other files like `.bash_profile` are still opened by Foxit Reader as default). How can I change back the file association with all files start with `.` to default?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change your default editor with this command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

It will prompt a list with all your editors, that you can choose to keep it or select another one as well.